# Would it be okay to have the Astrazeneca vaccine if I had dengue hemorrhagic fever as a child?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, dengue

Although it happened more than two decades ago, I still remember being very ill, vomiting so much blood at one point. I was given an IV drip and had to stay in hospital for a while.

Would having had severe dengue increase the risk of getting an adverse side effect from the AZ vaccine; in particular the very rare blood disorders that the vaccine can cause? Are the mechanisms which lead to the blood disorders caused by dengue and the vaccine even the same/related? I tried searching for some guidance online but the only thing I could find was a study from Brazil which suggests the possibility that having dengue can provide some protection from Covid 19, although I'm not sure if the study has been peer-reviewed.